# Display tk.Entry text in GUI as tk.Label (Python/Tkinter) Beginner level

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to learn how to program a GUI application to display text entered in the tk.Entry widget with a tk.Label widget.

code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()


def writelabel():
    label = tk.Label(window,text="abc" + entry)
    label.pack()


entry = tk.Entry(window)
entry.pack()


button = tk.Button(window,text="Display entry as GUI label", command=writelabel)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Code/Entry to Label.py", line 7, in writelabel
    label = tk.Label(window,text="abc" + entry)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Entry") to str
```

I have already attempted to string the command:

```
label = tk.Label(str(window,text="abc" + entry))
```

But I get the same output error as above:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Entry") to str
```

If I try to also string the entry widget :

```
entry = tk.Entry(str(window))
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The outcome I desire is for the text that the end user enters in to the tk.entry widget to display as a tk.label widget when the end user clicks on the tk.button widget.

*I know the answer is simple, but I just cant see it.*

Comment: Should be `"abc"+entry.get()`.

Comment: it worked as "abc" = str(entry.get())

Comment: `str()` is not necessary because `entry.get()` returns string.

Comment: I removed the str(), no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `StringVar()` function

```
v = StringVar()
```

set the argument textvariable to the variable v

```
entry = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=v)
entry.pack()
```

then inside the label widget you can use the v.get() method to get value from entry widget

```
label = tk.Label(window,text="abc" + v.get())
```

you can check the link for more
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I had to string the "entry" variable and include an .get().

IE.

```
def writelabel():
    label = tk.Label(window, text="abc " + str(entry.get()))
    label.pack()
```

Comment: by default, entry.get() is a string, there is no need for a conversion to `str()`